# How to open html page2, onclicking an image in html page1

Tags: javascript, html

How can i open html page2 in same html page1, when clicking any image in html page1

Please help me..

Comment: Are asking on how to set an HTML link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode your image around an anchor like following

```
<a href="/yourURL.html"><img src="yourimg.jpg" alt="pic" /></a>
```

Comment: Please fix your code and remove target blank - he wants to open in same page

Comment: @mplungjan thanks. How come i read that he wants to open new window. Has he edited the question or my mind has gone stupid :-P

Comment: Happens ;) No editing of the original

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your image in link tag with url of "page2".

```
<a href="page2"><img src="image/source" alt="page2" /></a>
```